# How can I handle no internet in case of electron-dl?

Tags: electron

I am trying to download a file via electron-dl and I want to gracefully end the download in case the internet goes off. I want to send a main to renderer event in case the download interrupts because of internet connection breaking down. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's up?

Electron has an event called online and offline:

```js
  window.addEventListener('online',  () => {})
  window.addEventListener('offline',  () => {})
```

And you can get the file with

```js
electronDL.onStart((item) => {
   window.addEventListener('offline',  () => {
     item.cancel();
   })
}))
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for The electron online offline events worked just perfectly. Thanks :D